# Git Checkout fails due to long file path names in the Azure DevOps yaml build pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the Unity project code in Azure DevOps Repos and configured the below yaml pipeline to build the Unity project.

```
trigger: 

- none

stages: 

  - stage: Build

    displayName: Unity Build

    jobs:

    - job: 'UnityBuild'

      displayName: 'Build the Unity application'

      pool:

        name: XXXXXXXXX

      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - script: "git config system core.longpaths true"
        - checkout: self

        - task: UnityBuildTask@3

          inputs:

            buildTarget: 'standalone'

            unityProjectPath: 'XXXXXXXXXX'

            outputPath: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

            outputFileName: 'Standalone'

        - task: UnityGetProjectVersionTask@1

          inputs:

            unityProjectPath: 'XXXXXXXXXX'

        - task: CopyFiles@2

          inputs:

            SourceFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

            Contents: '**'

            TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

          inputs:

            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

            ArtifactName: 'drop'

            publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Whenever I ran the yaml build pipeline, the build failed before it even executed unity build tasks due to file path name length restrictions.

How to fix the issue of file path names being too long in the Azure DevOps YAML pipeline?

Comment: It might depend on your agent. Are you using an MS-hosted agent, or a self-hosted one? Are you running on windows, or linux, or other?

Comment: I ma using custom windows agent.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what the error is? Knowing which task is erroring would help figure out exactly what is wrong and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script before "checkout" that tells Git.exe how to handle long paths (i.e. `git config --system core.longpaths true`).

See [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-on-building-azure-pipeline-error-unable-to-c/883582).

Comment: Could you please provide a sample yaml file in which the above git command is executed before the git checkout?

Comment: you need first to disable the checkout with `checkout: none`, then add `- script: git config --system core.longpaths true` and then `checkout: self`

Comment: I used this 
`steps:
- checkout: none
- script: git config --system core.longpaths true
- checkout: self` yaml snippet, but I got the following error: `When using multiple checkouts in a job, the checkout: none task is not allowed` in yaml azure devops pipeline.

Comment: Please look at my updated question with yaml code.

Comment: when you remove the `checkout: none` what happen?

Comment: If I remove the `checkout: none`, then I get an error as build failed due to file path name length restrictions.

Comment: check here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-checkout-from-github-fails-due-to-pathname-whe/1225807

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue :

```
error: unable to create file a/b/c/../file1.xml: Filename too long
error: unable to create file a/b/c/../file2.xml: Filename too long
error: unable to create file a/b/c/../file3.xml: Filename too long
```

To fix it, I followed the advice from @shayki-abramczyk. So I run `git config --system core.longpaths` before the checkout :

The pipeline.yml with the error :

```
jobs:
  - job: Job_1
    displayName: Agent Job 1
    pool:
      name: X
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: model
      - checkout: doc
```

The pipeline.yml with the fix :

```
jobs:
  - job: Job_1
    displayName: Agent Job 1
    pool:
      name: X
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: model
      
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            git config --system core.longpaths true

      - checkout: doc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for the entire day. Finally found something that is out of the box and works. If you are running a devops pipeline via yaml, you can simply add a parameter to enable long paths.

```
parameters:
  git:
    longpaths: true
```

Answer (score -1):

If the agent is running on your own Windows server, then you'll need to configure the server to [Enable Long Paths support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell).